# Delete file from the /usr/sbin

Tags: 11.10, modem-manager

What is the goal of /usr/sbin folder?

I found in that folder modem-manager, which makes me many problems. Can I delete it from that directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/bin (and /sbin) were intended for programs that needed to be on a small / partition before the larger /usr, etc. partitions were mounted. These days, it mostly serves as a standard location for key programs like /bin/sh, although the original intent may still be relevant for e.g. installations on small embedded devices.

/sbin, as distinct from /bin, is for system management programs (not normally used by ordinary users) needed before /usr is mounted.

/usr/bin is for distribution-managed normal user programs.

**/usr/sbin with the same relationship to /usr/bin as /sbin has to /bin.**

/usr/local/bin is for normal user programs not managed by the distribution package manager, e.g. locally compiled packages. You should not install them into /usr/bin because future distribution upgrades may modify or delete them without warning.

/usr/local/sbin, as you can probably guess at this point, is to /usr/local/bin as /usr/sbin to /usr/bin.

In addition, there is also /opt which is for monolithic non-distribution packages, although before they were properly integrated various distributions put Gnome and KDE there. Generally you should reserve it for large, poorly behaved third party packages such as Oracle.

**As far as deleting modem-manager goes, deleting the folder will probably only give you more problems if certain external programs are calling for it and its not there.  I would find out what the underlying problem is for why it is giving you so many problems.**

Comment: So, you should use the package manager (Synaptic, software center, apt-get) to remove the complete package, not just the single executable file. That way, you will see which other packages have this one as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You should never just delete system files, you will run into problems 100 %.

`/usr/sbin/ usually contains files with the »setuid« bit set – when executed they will run under their owning user instead of the user who executed them.

To remove modem-manager, find the package that contains that file and remove it using apt-get (hint: the package is named `modemmanager`, `sudo apt-get remove modemmanager` to remove it)